# NDS file format conversion to an executable GIS format

Tags: navigation

Could we open .nds files in any of the GIS mapping environment.

it stands for Navigation Data Standards, having the navigation features stored in it. There are 2 types of nds file formats. One is executable one (in sqlite interface) and the other non executable (because of its binary format). I want to customize these nds files to view the data stored in it. I require a software technology to open these files and view the stored data on any of the mapping software which is compatible.

Comment: Where do these .nds files come from? What software? What kind information are they expected to contain?

Comment: What GIS mapping environment do you have access to?

Comment: please add more details to the question to have more people interested in posting an answer

Comment: It seems like NDS is still being tested as a new car industry standard format for car navigation and maps. The only thing I could find was a company called Mapscape BV who is currently testing the format. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapscape_BV